# wpf ToolTip and Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, tooltip

How I can add   **ToolTip**   to this *code* ?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">  

</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set ToolTip property in a style the same way you set any other property.

Sample code as below

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">  
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="ToolTip Value" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more complex ToolTip use

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">  
    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
        <Setter.Value>
            <!--Content Here-->
            <!--<Grid> or <StackPanel> or <ContentPresenter>...-->
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```